# Jquery datepicker in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form with many fields. Two of them are for collecting a start date and an end date. Upon posting the form, the incorrect values in the other fields are remembered, while these two are not.

Also, if I add a datepicker with a model, with the code below, it doesn't show it:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.start_date, new { id = "datepicker" } ) %>
```

But if add it with this line, it does:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="start_date"/>
```

I think the fields, after posting, aren't displayed because I'm not bound to the model, so I would like to make it work the first, using the datepicker with a model, way.

What am I doing wrong, so the datepicker isn't displayed the first way?

Comment: try TextBoxFor helper

Comment: It works. Thank you. Would accept the answer if you write it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TextBoxFor` helper:

like this:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.start_date, new { id = "datepicker" } ) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add my 2 cents, as I had an annoying time getting the jQuery date-picker to work in VS2013.

After you've added the jQuery UI Combined package to your solution, and you are sure you have the script and script references correctly entered, check your BundleConfig, found in the App_Start folder.  Look for the following line:

```
 bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"))
```

Replace the word 'version' with the version of jQuery listed in your scripts folder.

And, just in case someone reading this doesn't know, an easy way to add a reference to jQuery is to right click on the appropriate listing in the Scripts folder, click copy, then past in your code.